# Crystal Report Selection Formula gives me only one row

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

how was the day?
I have a Problem related to Crystal Report in VS2010 where I designed my Crystal Report and connected it to Assessment.dbo in my Database and it works fine to display all Records.
But I use Selection Formula to display only one Student Record by typing Student ID in Sol.text with this code:

```
 REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.Enabled = True
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.ReportSource = "C:\Users\MUSTAPHA YUSUF\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SMS\SMS\Student_CrystalReport.rpt"
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.SelectionFormula = "{Assessment.ID}=" + Sol.Text
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.Refresh()
    REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.RefreshReport()
    REPORT_SHEET.Show()
```

The Problem is that, the Crystal Report only gives me first row of the Record not all the Records for the written Student ID in Sol.text.
Thank you very much for your usual help!

Comment: May you describe your table schema?

Comment: i have ID, Session, Term, Class, Subjects, 1stCA, 2ndCA, Exam, Total, Position, Grade, Remark in my table

Comment: in which section in the report are you placing your fields?

Comment: in details Section @Zeina

Comment: Can you add the grouping design of your report?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the Problem @Zeina, i found that the Problem comes from my Database where i must have int in my schema. so i created another column to assign that int and it works. Thank you very much for your usual Supports!

Comment: this is the code REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.SelectionFormula = "{Assessment.S_ID}=" + Sol.Text

Comment: this is the code                                            [REPORT_SHEET.CrvReport.SelectionFormula = "{Assessment.S_ID}=" + Sol.Text ] the new column is S_ID